# Advanced looping for Turbo Assember?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have created a program that will output the following letters:

```
W
V
U
T
S
R
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

M DB 'W'

.CODE

MAIN PROC FAR
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AX, 003H
INT 10H

MOV CX, 6
X:
MOV AH, 02
MOV DL, M
INT 21H
DEC M

MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, 10
INT 21H
MOV DL, 13
INT 21H
LOOP X

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
W
VW
UVW
TUVW
STUVW
RSTUVW
```

I'm sort of new in this programming language, and I'm really having a hard time trying to learn it.

Update:
Please see the code bellow.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data

.CODE
; mov     I, 0 
; WhileLp:        cmp     I, 100
; jge     WhileDone
; inc     I
; jmp     WhileLp

; for (CX = 6; CX != 0; CX--) {
    ; for (BL = 0; BL != 7-CX; BL++) {
        ; putchar(M+BL);
; }    
    ; M--;
    ; putchar(10);
    ; putchar(13);
; }

M DB 'W'

MAIN PROC FAR
MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX
MOV AX, 003H
INT 10H

MOV CX, 6
WHILECX:

MOV AL, 7
WHILEBL: 
SUB CL, AL
CMP BL, CL
JGE WHILEDONE
MOV AH, 02
MOV DL, M
INT 21H
MOV DL, BL
INT 21H
INC BL
JNE WHILEBL
DEC M

WHILEDONE:
MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, 10
INT 21H
MOV DL, 13
INT 21H
LOOP WHILECX

MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: I have tried using loops and putting in a new loop inside the loop. I just don't know how to do this in assembly. I haven't mastered the registers I'm afraid. So far I'm so newb in this language.

Comment: There's really no point in trying to rush ahead without having understood the basics. You'll just keep running into problems you're unable to solve again and again. Find a book or tutorial on x86 assembly and read it, then return to this problem and see if you can solve it.

Comment: Sorry, but we are only given a day to solve this. I'm still looking for a good guide to read. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put another loop inside your current loop (you don't necessarily have to use the `LOOP` instruction for that) which prints `7-CX` characters starting with M.
So on the first iteration of the outer loop you'll do the inner loop 7-6 == 1 time and it will print 'W'. The next time you'll do the inner loop 7-5 == 2 times and M will have an initial value of 'V' so you'll print "VW". And so on.

Pseudo-code for the whole thing:

```
for (CX = 6; CX != 0; CX--) {
    for (BL = 0; BL != 7-CX; BL++) {
        putchar(M+BL);
    }
    M--;
    putchar(10);
    putchar(13);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do loops with conditions in Assembly Language. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: In my example it would be something like `INC BL` / `CMP BL,someValue` / `JNE label`

Comment: How do I compare BL to 7-CX? I mean How can I check if they are not equal?

Comment: Set another byte register to 7, subtract `CL` from it and then compare it against the counter register (`BL` in my example). Consult Intel's developer manuals for an instruction set reference and register list.

Comment: I edited my post. Please take a look, for some reason the output turned out to be blank.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you, our professor never really thought us the basics.